# How does RVM gets invoked while going into a folder with Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line, rvm

I am surprised at how RVM switches Ruby versions honouring Gemfile just by navigating into the directory via command-line? Is RVM getting a call back through the shell? Can anyone provide a pointer on this?

For instance message like this:

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /directory/path/to/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory

rvm redefines the cd command.  If I do what Amadan suggested, I get:

```
~$ type cd
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    __zsh_like_cd cd "$@"
}
```

That looks like some kind of alias, so let's try:

```
~$ type __zsh_like_cd
__zsh_like_cd is a function
__zsh_like_cd () 
{ 
    typeset __zsh_like_cd_hook;
    if builtin "$@"; then
        shift || true;
        for __zsh_like_cd_hook in chpwd "${chpwd_functions[@]}";
        do
            if typeset -f "$__zsh_like_cd_hook" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                "$__zsh_like_cd_hook" "$@" || break;
            fi;
        done;
        true;
    else
        return $?;
    fi
}
```

In a zsh shell, chpwd is a hook function that is called when the current directory changes.  But, I'm not sure why that works in a bash shell, which doesn't provide the chpwd hook function.  Amadan?

Comment: It doesn't "work" in `bash`, not as you imagine :) - the `chpwd` is never executed in `bash`. `for __zsh_like_cd_hook in chpwd "${chpwd_functions[@]}"` merely iterates over `chpwd` and anything in `$chpwd_functions`, not executing anything. Then `if typeset -f $__zsh_like_cd_hook` fails for `chpwd` and does nothing. On my machine, it will next test for `__rvm_cd_functions_set` and `__rvm_after_cd`, which both do exist, and therefore get executed in the next line (unless one of them fails, which aborts the loop).

Comment: But is redefining such a fundamental command recommendable? How is the permissions for linking to a call back like this handled? Can a script running with root privileges modify zshrc?

Comment: @Amadan, I don't know why my answer was accepted instead of yours--you are the only one that knows what's going on in this thread, so ++ for you.

Comment: @7stud: Haha, it's fine. As long as the question is answered, you know. I have enough rep anyway :)

Comment: @JikkuJose: Some people don't like RVM specifically because of the magic; they'll typically use `rbenv` project instead. But I have never had any trouble so far, nor have I heard of anyone like that. There is no linking possible, since it is a function, not a file. A script running as root can indeed modify `.zshrc`; it can also wipe your account or do anything else it wants, so it is a moot point. It's like worrying about whether or not an arsonist can burn a paper on your desk when he has your whole house already soaked in gasoline.

Comment: @Amadan, *It's like worrying about whether or not an arsonist can burn a paper on your desk when he has your whole house already soaked in gasoline.* -- lol.

Comment: To disable this "feature", set set `rvm_project_rvmrc=0` in `/etc/rvmrc` or `$HOME/.rvmrc`. (from the comment at the top of rvm/scripts/cd)

Answer (score 2):

Normally `cd` is a shell builtin. `rvm` defines `cd` function which gets invoked instead. Do this to see for yourself:

```
$ type cd
```

Then try it in a "clean" shell, to see the difference:

```
$ env -i PATH=$PATH HOME=$HOME bash -c "type cd"
```