# Git Bash - cd command says which: no bundle in

Tags: bash, rvm, git-bash, cd

I am working with Git Bash on Windows and I have installed Gpg4win and RVM the other day. Since then whenever I use the cd command in the bash, e.g.

```
$ cd onedrive
```

it comes up with:

```
which: no bundle in (/c/Users/jonas/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/jonas/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cmd:/c/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin:/c/Program Files/GitHub CLI:/c/Ruby31-x64/bin:/c/Users/jonas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts:/c/Users/jonas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39:/c/Users/jonas/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/jonas/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/Program Files/heroku/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/c/Users/jonas/.rvm/bin)
```

It does still change the directory - it's just a bit annoying it always comes up with all that text.

.bash_profile file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

.bashrc file:

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

.profile file:

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

I tried deleting everything in the .bash_profile, .profile and .bashrc files but that didn't make a difference.

Also:

```
$ type cd
cd is a function
cd ()
{
    __zsh_like_cd cd "$@"
}
```

And:

```
$ printf 'PS1=%q\n' "$PS1"
PS1=\\\[\\033\]0\;\$TITLEPREFIX:\$PWD\\007\\\]\\n\\\[\\033\[32m\\\]\\u@\\h\ \\\[\\033\[35m\\\]\$MSYSTEM\ \\\[\\033\[33m\\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[36m\\\]\`__git_ps1\`\\\[\\033\[0m\\\]\\n\$\
```

And finally:

```
$ PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+'
+ PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+'
:::1+__git_ps1
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:2+local exit=0
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:3+local pcmode=no
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:4+local detached=no
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:5+local 'ps1pc_start=\u@\h:\w '
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:6+local 'ps1pc_end=\$ '
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:7+local 'printf_format= (%s)'
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:352+case "$#" in
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:19+printf_format=' (%s)'
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:58+local ps1_expanded=yes
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:59+'[' -z '' ']'
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:60+'[' -z '4.4.23(1)-release' ']'
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:60+shopt -q promptvars
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:62+local repo_info rev_parse_exit_code
:::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:0+git rev-parse --git-dir --is-inside-git-dir --is-bare-repository --is-inside-work-tree --short HEAD
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:65+repo_info=
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:66+rev_parse_exit_code=128
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:68+'[' -z '' ']'
::C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh:69+return 0
```

Any other ideas what to try?

Comment: What do you get for `type cd`, and for `echo $PS1`?

Comment: Use `set -x` to enable debugging, and `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+'` to make those debug logs tell you where everything it does was defined, before running a `cd` command; then you can use `set +x` to turn the logging back off.

Comment: (btw, `declare -p PS1` or `printf 'PS1=%q\n' "$PS1"` will give you more accurate output than `echo $PS1` in the corner cases; even `echo "$PS1"` is a _little_ better; cc: @SiKing).

Comment: That said, insofar as `bundle` is a ruby tool, this smells _very_ much like an rvm problem. (And if it is one, use of `which` instead of `command -v` does not reflect well on rvm's author).

Comment: My money is on `__zsh_like_cd` being the source of your problem. I have no idea what that is, but that is where I would look first. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562097/3124333) will be of some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have uninstalled rvm (`rvm implode`) and re-installed it and now it all works fine.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you have done to fix the issue please ?

Comment: I typed in "rvm implode" (to uninstall rvm) and then installed it again. You can find information on how to do this on the rvm website.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and I resolved it using

`gem install bundler`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is caused from RVM.
And to turnaround this issue you have simply to install the Ruby Gem bundler available on your distro Repo.
So for instance on Fedora:

```
sudo dnf in rubygem-bundler
```